# DocuSign Gen Salesforce : Generate doc with Apex Code

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

Can I generate a document for an account from a created DocuSign template with apex code ?

I could not find resources for it. I saw some code to generate envelopes but nothing to generate documents.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you use CLM?

Comment: No, I don't use CLM !

Comment: Then you cannot do this with DocuSign alone, you can use some other third party to generate documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, I tell you that Apex Toolkit does not support document generation, only envelopes.

Regards,

Eric | DocuSign